# Django: How to reference a model's objects from a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a django ecommerce site that sells jewelry.  I have a `Product` model, with an associated `show_product` view, which is displayed by a `product.html` template.

I now want to offer customizable charms with my jewelry.  To that end, I have created a `Charm` model which defines the name, image, SKU etc. of the charms.  I have also modified my `Product` model to include an `allows_charms` boolean value, since every charm is available on any product that allows charms in the first place.  In other words, I don't have to worry about relational mapping, because as long as a product ALLOWS charms, it allows ALL charms.

My problem is arising in the `show_product` view.  How do I set a `charms` variable that contains all of the `Charm` model's objects, which I can then reference in my template, with code something like:

```
{% for ch in charms %}
<div class="charm_thumb">
     <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/charms/{{ ch.image }}" alt="{{ ch.name }}" />
     <p id="charm_name">{{ ch.name }}</p>
     <p id="charm_price">${{ ch.price }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I would know how to do this if I was grabbing a list of associated charms from a M2M relationship of an object of a product model, but I don't know how to grab EVERY object in a given model?

To make my end-goal clear, I wish something like this, NON FUNCTIONAL, code would work:

```
from mystore import Charms
charms = Charms.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model.objects.all()` returns all objects of a given model, e.g. `Charm.objects.all()`.

- [Retrieving all objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects) (the database query guide)
- [The all method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all)
- [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#)

Comment: Argh!  I was one step away!  Thanks a bunch :)